# .toList() method inserts spaces after comma

Tags: java, list

So I try to convert a string as follows: `[srv3,Backupserver,  500,  250]` to a List of JavaFX (FXCollections.observableArrayList())

The problem is, when I try to convert it to a list, I can't get rid of the spaces after the comma. This is very problematic for other parts of my code.

This happens:
`[srv3,Backupserver,  500,  250] - String => [srv3, Backupserver,   500,   250] - List`

This should happen:
`[srv3,Backupserver,  500,  250] - String => [srv3,Backupserver,  500,  250] - List`

The code I already have is as follows

```
tableList.forEach(item -> { data.add(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.stream(item
                        .replace("[", "")
                        .replace("]", "")
                        .split(","))
                        .toList()));
});
```

Comment: Change `.split(",")` to `.split("\\s*,\\s*")` (**glob** *optional* whitespace on either side of the `,`).

Comment: With this solution it didn't quite work, the second part is displayed correctly, but the third and fourth elements no longer have spaces in the table. When I print the added string, the second part does not change.

Comment: Why do you `Arrays.stream(…).toList()` and not simply `Arrays.asList(…)`? Do you require an immutable list?

Comment: Since you already have a stream, why don't you `map(String::trim)` before collecting?

Comment: I didn't think of such stream methods, thanks for the idea. Your Arrays.asList(...) approach (in my case now List.of(...)) worked as I want it to work.

Comment: Strangely, your initial `String` itself looks like the result of some sort of `List.toString` method, in which case, some sort of double processing is going on

Comment: The spaces are in the data items. `toList()` produces a list, not a string.

Comment: The first words of the question: *So I try to convert a string as follows*

Comment: @g00se I try to use good english, I'm not a native english speaker

Comment: Actually my comment was addressed to @user207421 rather than as a general observation. I was simply saying that you're starting with a string not a list. That is the case is it not? Also is your question answered satisfactorily?

Comment: To put it more directly: why is `tableList` a String?  Why is it not a Collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're showing no spaces between `srv3` and `Backupserver` in the desired output, I am presuming you have three items in the string you want to place in a list.  Namely

```
srv3,Backupserver
500
250
```

So you could do this.

```
String s = "[srv3,Backupserver, 500, 250]";
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
    .split(",\\s+")).toList();
System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[srv3,Backupserver, 500, 250]
```